# IdentityServer authentication using user X509 certificate

Tags: authentication, certificate, x509, identityserver3

I am working with IdentityServer3 and I need the user to authenticate using a X509 certificate (instead of user/pass). I am trying to achieve this through a Partial Login implementing IUserService (on the PreAuthenticateAsync), but unfortunately I don't get any possible option to request this from the "PreAuthenticationContext context" -  open the browser X509 user certificate store so the user selects one and proceed.
Could anyone provide me a helping hand on this please?
Many thanks in advance!